# Command substitution doesn't work when it's the input to `read`

Tags: command-line, bash

If I run the following script of command substitution:

```
var=$(ls)
echo $var
```

it works as expected -- the output is the results of `ls` command. But if I assign the variable using read:

```
read var
echo $var
```

in which $(ls) is the input to `read`, the output is the literal

```
$(ls)
```

instead of the output of the `ls` command.

I don't understand why there is such a difference because I think the contents of variable `var` should be the same in both cases and therefore the shell should treat the `echo` command in both exactly the same way.

Could you please give an explanation?

Comment: please provide the full `read var` line, I don't see `$(ls)` being the input here.

Comment: Bare `read` will just take a line of what you type into the shell. Specifically, it reads `stdin` stream. So whatever goes into `var` in  `read var` is what you've typed. That's why it makes no sense how you got `$(ls)` string into it unless you typed that out while executing `read`

Comment: On another note before you get any ideas: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do do instead)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/47852)

Answer (score 3):

Command substitution is a shell expansion, and Bash doesn't perform expansions on the input to `read`.

This is a good thing, because `read` is supposed to capture whatever nonsense (or brilliance) the naive (or expert) user typed.

Try entering any input that the shell would usually expand, and you will find the same thing happens...

```
$ var=~          # ~ was expanded before assignment
$ echo $var
/home/zanna
$ read -r var
~
$ echo $var
~
```

There are some sort-of exceptions to this - `read` treats backslash characters as escapes

> The backslash character ‘\’ may be used to remove any special meaning for the next character read and for line continuation.

This is almost never what you actually want (you want `read` to capture *whatever the user typed* including any backslashes), so you should habitually use the `-r` flag with `read` (like I have done in my examples):

> -r
>
> If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.

The other exception is that the input is split into fields in a way similar to word-splitting, so you can assign to multiple variables:

```
$ read -r var
one two three
$ echo $var
one two three
$ read -r baa ram ewe
one two three
$ echo $ram
two
```

Quotes are from [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) of the Bash manual - scroll down to find `read`, or run `help read` in the shell for a shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

`var=$(ls)` executes command ls and assigns the output to a variable
In the second case, it just assigns the string you entered to a variable, there is no execution happening. It is just a string assigned to a variable, bash does not do anything with it.